# Prolog: Return a list of facts from a list of atoms

Tags: list, prolog

I highly doubt it is possible, but I'm wondering is there is a way to transform a list of atoms into a list of fact. It is assumed that there won't be repetition of atoms between two facts.

More precisely, say I have the following list of facts:

```
person(Mike, male, 33).
person(Frank, male, 24).
person(Julie, female, 25).
```

And I want to call

```
listFacts( [Mike, Frank], L).
```

Which should return,

```
L = [person(Mike, male, 33), person(Frank, male, 24)].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using variables (the tokens starting with uppercase letters). You must switch to constants (in this case, atoms): `Mike` -> `mike`

After that it's easy going, using `setof/3`:

```
person(mike, male, 33).
person(frank, male, 24).
person(julie, female, 25).

listFacts( Names, List ) :-
   setof(person(Name,S,A), (member(Name,Names),person(Name,S,A)), List).
```

Which means: Find answers for `Name` taken from `Names` for which a fact `person(Name,S,A)` exists and put a corresponding term `person(Name,S,A)` into a set (actually a list) called `List`.

And so:

```
?- listFacts([mike,frank],F).
F = [person(frank, male, 24), person(mike, male, 33)].
```

The variation which is existentially qualified also works:

```
listFacts( Names, List ) :-
   setof(person(Name,S,A), Name^(member(Name,Names),person(Name,S,A)), List).
```

Properly, it should not as it is the same as:

```
listFacts( Names, List ) :-
   setof(person(_Name,S,A), subgoal(Names,S,A), List). 

subgoal(Names,S,A) :-
   member(Name,Names),
   person(Name,S,A).
```

and that gives us no info about the `Name`:

```
?- listFacts([mike,frank],F).
F = [person(_6478, male, 24), person(_6492, male, 33)].
```

Comment: The example is working perfectly, I learned a lot from this post, I appreciate the help.